# how to use javascript this keyword with change function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having a trouble using change function. I have a 2 different dropdowns attached to each other. When the first one is changes, the second one changes too. I did it using jquery ajax. But when i use ID's jquery can only work one time. So i did a research about javascript's this,parent and children keyword but i can't find the suitable way.

so my javascript is like below :

```
    <script>
           $(document).ready(function() {
            //  alert('js working');
            $(".catSelectedClass").change(function() {
                //  alert('i'm inside the function dude');
                function ustCat() {         
                    alert(this);
                    var mainCatID = $(this).val();
                    alert('mainCatID captured');
                    var id = $(this).parent().$(".catIDClass").val();
                    //  alert(id);
                    //  alert(mainCatID);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "panel/catGroupPost.php",
                        data: {id: id, mainCatID: mainCatID}
                    }).done(function(data) {
                        var responseData = data;

                        alert(responseData);
                        $('#subCat').html($(data));

                    });
                }
                ustCat();
            });
            $(".subCatClass").change(function() {

                function subCat() {
                    var mainCatID = $(this).val();
                    var id = $('#catID').val();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "panel/subCatPost.php",
                        data: {id: id, mainCatID: mainCatID}
                    }).done(function() {
                        alert('its done. its gone. Yes Mr.Frodo. Its all over now !!');
                    });
                }
                subCat();
            });
        });

    </script>
```

And this is how a fill dropdowns :

```
 while ($cat = mysql_fetch_array($cat_query)) {


$catTable.= '<label>' . $cat['name'] . '</label>';
$catTable.= '<div class="catContainer"><div id="catPost" class="catPostClass">';
$catTable.= '<input type="text" id="catID" class="catIDClass" value="' . $cat['id'] . '"><select id="catSelected" class="catSelectedClass" name="catSelected"><option value="0">Seçiniz...</option>' . catOption($cat['mainCatID']) . '</select></div>';
$kategoriTablosu.= '<div id="subCat"><select id="subCatID" class="SubCatClass"><option value="0">Seçiniz...</option>' . subCatOption($cat['mainCatID']) . '</select></div></div>';


}
```

My both functions:

```
  function catOption($id) {
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mainCats WHERE id=mainCatID") or die(mysql_error());
$arrCat = "";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $arrCat .= '<option value="' . $row['mainCatID'] . '"';
    if ($row['id'] == $id) {
        $catSelected = 'selected="selected"';
    } else {
        $catSelected = "";
    }

    $arrCat .= '' . $catSelected . '>' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
}
return $arrCat;
 }
```

And :

```
    function subCatOption($subID) {

$subCat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mainCats WHERE mainCatID='$subID' ORDER BY id ") or die(mysql_error());
$subArrCat = "";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($subCat)) {
    $subArrCat .= '<option value="' . $row['mainCatID'] . '"';
    if ($row['mainCatID'] == $subID) {
        $catSelected = 'selected="selected"';
    } else {
        $catSelected = "";
    }

    $subArrCat .= '' . $catSelected . '>' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
}
return $subArrCat;
  }
```

Thanks for any help !

Comment: And what was the question?

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions as they are deprecated, and element IDs on the page should be unique. That would also make it easier for you to select proper element. About this, you need to assign it to a new variable at the top of the change function - as soon as you enter another function, this will refer to its new context.

Comment: @putvande it's in the title

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ya4UHuXNygM

Comment: One possible problem: in your `while` loop you are assigning always the same ID to your html elements (e.g.: `id="subCat"`). In the JavaScript you are referencing them, which will be a problem. Every ID has to be unique in the HTML. A solution would be to use `id="subCat' . $row['id'] . '"'` to make them unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your code as

```
$(".catSelectedClass").change(function() {
    var mainCatID = $(this).val();
    //Rest of code....
});
```

Instead of

```
$(".catSelectedClass").change(function() {
    //  alert('i'm inside the function dude');
    function ustCat() { 
        var mainCatID = $(this).val();
        //Rest of code....
    }
});
```

Same with `$(".subCatClass").change(function() {`

General Syntax

```
$(selector).change(function() {
  //do something
});
```

If you have already defined function use

```
$(selector).change(your_defined_function);
```

in your case you can use

```
  $(".catSelectedClass").change(ustCat);
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you call a function in the event handler. If you instead put the code inside the event handler or you turn the function in the handler it should fix your problem. I suggest to make the function the event handler. So just put the ustCat on its own and use the following to make the function the handler

```
$(".catSelectedClass").change(ustCat);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the functions inside the change function. You can simply do:

```
$(".catSelectedClass").change(function () {
    //  alert('i'm inside the function dude');
    alert(this);
    var mainCatID = $(this).val();
    alert('mainCatID captured');
    var id = $(this).parent().$(".catIDClass").val();
    //  alert(id);
    //  alert(mainCatID);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "panel/catGroupPost.php",
        data: {
            id: id,
            mainCatID: mainCatID
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        var responseData = data;

        alert(responseData);
        $('#subCat').html($(data));

    });

});
$(".subCatClass").change(function () {
    var mainCatID = $(this).val();
    var id = $('#catID').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "panel/subCatPost.php",
        data: {
            id: id,
            mainCatID: mainCatID
        }
    }).done(function () {
        alert('its done. its gone. Yes Mr.Frodo. Its all over now !!');
    });
});
```

The way you did it `this` was in the wrong scope. `this` would be `window`.

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to do it.

You don't really need to define ustCat, you can just put the code inside the change function :

```
$(".catSelectedClass").change(function() {
    var mainCatID = $(this).val();
    ....
});
```

Or assign the parent before you call your inner function :

```
$(".catSelectedClass").change(function() {
    (function ustCat(self){
        var mainCatID = self.val();
        ......
    })($(this));
});
```

Or put the ustCat function elsewere and just pass it to the change handler :

```
function ustCat(){ var mainCatID = $(this).val(); ...... };
$(".catSelectedClass").change(ustCat);
```